# How to plot scientific diagrams?

Tags: drawing

I'm looking for a way for drawing scientific graphs, mostly vectors, coordinate systems and diagrams, for example like this one: [diagram](http://zone.ni.com/cms/images/devzone/tut/a/2f52fe69817.gif)

I'm not looking for data visualization software, I need something that I can use to sketch a process, illustrate physical aspects of a system, without specific data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Packages that spring to mind include

Asymptote - http://asymptote.sourceforge.net

Geogebra - http://www.geogebra.org/cms/en/

and Geometer's Sketchpad  - http://www.dynamicgeometry.com

Answer (score 0):

You should [check this great thread](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/401/what-software-programs-are-used-to-draw-physics-diagrams-and-what-are-their-rel)...
I should probably say inkscape, but I love MetaPost.

MetaPost is a very simple and powerful language that allows you to design just about any professional physics or mathematics graphic.